# unable to get code block formatted right

Tags: support, formatting

look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/280615/Ubuntu-10-10-getting-appropiate-monitor-resolution-for-lcd-hdtv/280866#280866), at the bottom there is a C code block, I tried formatting with the code sample button, manually, and nothing works, it looks all weird

any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` in Markdown corresponds to `<h1>` in HTML, so having a `#include` was causing Markdown parser to incorrectly think of it as heading. Adding a separator ( `----------` ) forces the break and causes it to parse correctly.